# Getting one line from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of account transactions. Some of these transactions are triggers by a scheduled event. I need to list all the scheduled events, and show the latest transaction that was triggered by that schedule.

So, I have a table with transactions:

```
transaction_id
amount
scheduled_transaction_id (NULLABLE)
transaction_date
```

And then a schedule table:

```
scheduled_tranaction_id
```

What I need to do is, as I say, get a list of all the scheduled transactions, with the last transaction date for that schedule:

Return scheduled_transaction_id, transaction_date, amount

Can I do this with a join? I was thinking of maybe creating a temp table with all the latest transactions, for each scheduled_transaction_id, and ordering by transaction_date desc, and somehow, getting just one for each schedule. And then join to that temp table.

But is that efficient?

Comment: do you really need join? I mean do you need scheduled_transaction details

Comment: I think so, but may be wrong. I need to list all the schedules, along with the latest associated transaction for that schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, you'll need to join and group the results. I don't know the tables names and are assuming some things here. But probably you'll want something like:

```
SELECT st.scheduled_transaction_id, 
       MAX(tr.transaction_date) 
FROM   scheduled_transactions st 
       LEFT JOIN transactions tr 
              ON st.scheduled_transaction_id = tr.scheduled_transaction_id 
GROUP  BY st.scheduled_transaction_id
```

If you need more columns, you'll have to `GROUP BY` those columns as well, or use `AGGREGATE` functions like `MAX` on them.

Comment: SO is asking to list only the transactions that are scheduled. scheduled_transaction_id is nullable!

Comment: I think the answer is right... the LEFT JOIN handles the nullable part. Trying it now.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` indeed only selects from the left side if it isn't `NULL`.